# Resizable Iframe for facebook iframe applications

Tags: facebook

I have an iframe application build up on php.

I have set iframe size as resizable.

There is a problem the display is not proper if the content is too large.

I have applied the code available on http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Resizable_IFrame

My `xd_receiver.htm` file is inside my templates folder where my php files are residing.

The code which I am using is:

```
<div id="FB_HiddenIFrameContainer" style="display:none; position:absolute; left:-100px; top:-100px; width:0px; height: 0px;"></div> 
<script src="http://static.ak.facebook.com/js/api_lib/v0.4/FeatureLoader.js.php" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
FB_RequireFeatures(["CanvasUtil"], function(){
    FB.XdComm.Server.init(xd_receiver.htm>); 
    FB.CanvasClient.startTimerToSizeToContent(); 
    }
); 
</script>
```

Please guide on how to make the display correct.

Answer (score 0):

even though In am not sure about this, but Large content could be the the real issue,

try to move this part to the end of your page

> FB_RequireFeatures(["CanvasUtil"],
>   function(){
>       FB.XdComm.Server.init(xd_receiver.htm>);
>
> ```
> FB.CanvasClient.startTimerToSizeToContent();
>
> } );  </script>
> ```